# MySQL create a nullable foreign key that refers to the id field on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, foreign-keys, self-referencing-table

Iam trying to make the "in_reply_to" field in the Post table a nullable foreign key that refers to the id field on the same table. Basically so if this field is null, then the post is not a reply to another post – if it is non-null then the
post is a reply to the post with the matching id if that makes any sense. But when i run my file through mysql i get the following error.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(160)
,
                FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(userID),
                FOREIGN KEY (in_reply_' at line 6
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

So it is saying something is wrong with the commands i have written, but i cant pinpoint what iam doing wrong.

Here is the contents of the sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE siteData CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

 USE siteData;

 CREATE TABLE users (
userID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(40),
email VARCHAR(40),
password VARCHAR(125)
);

 CREATE TABLE post (
postID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
userID INT,
post_date TIMESTAMP(6),
in_reply_to INT NOT NULL,
postContent(160),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (in_reply_to) REFERENCES post(postID)   
); 

 CREATE TABLE follow (
userID INT,
followerID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (userID,followerID),

FOREIGN KEY (userID)
        REFERENCES users(userID),
FOREIGN KEY (followerID)
        REFERENCES users(userID)
);
```

So if you have any pointers on how to make it reference the id of post, i would appreciate it.

Comment: The error is `postContent(160),`, I would guess it should be `postContent VARCHAR(160),`. Your actual foreign keys are fine. Although I would suggest you want `in_reply_to ` to be not null -- `in_reply_to INT NULL,` rather than `in_reply_to INT NOT NULL,`

Comment: Thankyou, i cant believe it was something so stupid that i forgot.

Comment: thankyou for your help and tips, i ran it and no errors :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the foreign key. You haven't declared the type for column `postContent`.

Please change

```
postContent(160),
```

to e.g.

```
postContent varchar(160),
```

If you want your column `in_reply_to` to be nullable, please change

```
in_reply_to INT NOT NULL,
```

to

```
in_reply_to INT,
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake, thankyou Mario for your help and tips. Ran it with no errors!

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing Datatype of field postContent in Post Table. But this is not the right way to make foreign key null. Still there is a trick to do that. You can check the following link.

[Foreign keys and NULL in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802545/foreign-keys-and-null-in-mysql)